# I want fetched questions in FACEBOOK GROUP using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-group

I fetched posts in facebook group using below FQL, but I found that they except question posts in fetched posts.

Used FQL Query:

```
SELECT post_id, created_time, permalink, message 
FROM stream WHERE source_id = [group_id]
```

I used below FQL, and I fetch question which is a people belong specific facebook group.

```
SELECT created_time, id, is_published, question, owner, updated_time 
FROM question WHERE owner = 'object_id'
```

I want to know relationship  between question table and stream tables in FQL.

and I want to fetch all questions posts in specific facebook group.

thank you for the tip.

Comment: Could you clarify the question, I might be able to help you but I don't understand the question. you "want to fetch questions in a Facebook Group" but it throws an exception ? Because I read sth like "I found that exception question" ?

Comment: Thank you for replay. I want to fetch questions in facebook group. thus, I were used FQL => `SELECT post_id, created_time, permalink, message 
FROM stream WHERE source_id = [group_id]`, but question in group except from the fetched post. I guess that they excpet question.

Comment: and I found that questions is contained question table. I want to know relationship between questions table and stream table.

Comment: finally, I want to fetch all questions in specific facebook group using FQL.

Comment: It seems to be not supported at all, the closest you can get is `SELECT id, owner,question FROM question WHERE owner IN(SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = 'yourGroupId');` But as you probably noticed that it only gives you the questions that all users from a group ever created. Not necessarily in the stream of that group. And there is no other indexable/filterable field in the question column. So I am afraid the answer is : Impossible (and I am not taking the permissions scopes in consideration which would limit it even more).

Comment: I appreciate your replay. I have been helped your reply. :)

Comment: I shall post is as an answer so you can accept it if you want to ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments earlier.

It seems to be not supported at all, the closest you can get is

```
SELECT id, owner,question FROM question WHERE owner IN(SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = 'yourGroupId');
```

But as you probably noticed that it only gives you the questions that all users from a group ever created. Not necessarily in the stream of that group. And there is no other indexable/filterable field in the question column. So I am afraid **the answer is : Impossible** (and I am not taking the permissions scopes in consideration which would limit it even more).